# php fopen works only first time

Tags: php, serial-port, fopen

I'm writing on rs232 /dev/ttyUSB0 on debian but it will work only first or two time

This is my code

```
    $fp = fopen('/dev/ttyUSB0', 'r+');
    stream_set_blocking($fp,1);
    fwrite($fp, $output);

    // Set timeout to 500 ms
    $timeout=microtime(true)+0.5;
    // Set non blocking mode for reading
    stream_set_blocking($fp,0);
    do{
      // Try to read one character from the device
      $c=fgetc($fp);
      // Wait for data to arive
      if($c === false){
          usleep(50000);
          continue;
      }
      $line.=$c;
    }while($c!="\n" && microtime(true)<$timeout);

    fclose($fp);
```

I have also tried to set fopen on w+ with same result

Comment: Doesn't this run your loop only short, because the timeout is reached after half a second? or is this on purpose?

Comment: also without do while I have same result

Comment: what is the error output? Is the device at `/dev/ttyUSB0` always "ready" (e.g. is connecting to it with e.g. [`screen`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/5-linux-unix-commands-for-connecting-to-the-serial-console/) always working)? And: out of interest: what kind of device are you connecting to?